# How does AMP-HTML page load javascript from rails/app/assets/javascript folder?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, amp-html

Before AMP I was using `javascript_include_tag 'application'` for including all js files but now after AMP implementation it shows error:

```
The tag 'script' is disallowed except in specific forms
```

AMP supports `async` attribute and `application/json+ld` type in `script` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of 2017 you can use the [amphtml](https://rubygems.org/gems/amphtml) gem with its javascript component to build strong rails applications with custom javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Can't have any non-AMP provided JavaScript code in AMP, only the JavaScript that is provided by the Google AMP team may exist on AMP pages as per [AMP's specifications](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec.html).

Comment: Is there any alternative so that I can include rails-js files in AMP-HTML ? @Butter

Comment: You can go request for the AMP team to add support for it on github. That's the only way I can think of possibly including rails-js.

Answer (score 0):

You can not render custom javascript files into amp pages. However amp provides almost all replacements of javascript libraries. You just need to go through the amp components here https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components

and build your functionalities using amp components.